# How can I make it where only certain roles like moderators can use the kick and ban command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

This is my code and I'm trying to make it where only moderators or roles I choose are able to use the Kick and Ban command.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You coudn't kick that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you have everything set up based on what I saw in the code, what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: do you have to login to the site?

Comment: Check the roles on `message.author`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, I just would like to know if I wanted to make it where only moderators can use the command ~Kick or ~Ban what code what I have to add?